# passing arguments from the user

Tags: java, methods, parameters, arguments

```java
package p1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class P1 {
    public static void mile(double mpg, double miles, double gallons) {
        mpg = miles/gallons;
        System.out.println("you drove" + miles + "milkes");
        System.out.println("You uses" + gallons + "gallons");
        System.out.println("The mpg is" + mpg);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your name : ");
        String str = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the value of miles");
        double miles = sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter the value of gallons");
        double gallons = sc.nextDouble();
        mile();
    }
}
```

I want to take inputs dynamically, what should I do to take inputs from the user?

I am getting this error:

> The method mile(double, double, double) in the type P1 is not applicable for the arguments()

Comment: You're not calling `mile` with any parameters; it takes parameters.

Answer (score 1):

- `mpg` should not be a parameter but a local variable inside the `mile` function.
- Pass `miles` and `gallons` to the `mile` function when calling it.

```java
public static void mile(double miles, double gallons) {
    double mpg = miles/gallons;
    System.out.println("you drove" + miles + "milkes");
    System.out.println("You uses" + gallons + "gallons");
    System.out.println("The mpg is" + mpg);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // ...
    mile(miles, gallons);
}
```